# jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer throws Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot to display my bar char.

The bar chart worked fine until I added tickRenderer and tickOptions.

Now I get the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Here is my code

```
plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s2, s3], {
    stackSeries: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            highlightMouseDown: true
        },
        pointLabels: {show: true}
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        location: 'e',
        placement: 'outside'
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks,
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
            tickOptions: {
                angle: -90,
                fontSize: '10pt'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried your code and it works...
I don't know what is your problem.

I included these plugins

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
```

and i used these data arrays for testing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 s2 = [0,1,2,3,4];
 s3 = [1,2,3,4,5];
 ticks = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
```

this is the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was loading my scripts dynamically, but my loadScript() function was asyc, so not all resources were loaded before drawing the chart. After changing async to false everything started working.

```
loadScript("jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js");
loadScript("jqplot/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js");
loadScript("jqplot/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js");
loadScript("jqplot/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js");
loadScript("jqplot/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js");
loadScript("jqplot/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js");
loadScript("jqplot/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js");

function loadScript(jsPage) {
    $.ajax({
        url: jsPage,
        async: false,
        dataType: "script"
    });
}
```